# Can you say « L'iPhone 8 s'arrache » instead of « Tout le monde s'arrache l'iPhone 8 »?

Tags: expressions

> Tout le monde ***s'arrache*** l'iPhone 8.

I usually use this sentence construction, with people as the subject and the thing sought-after as the object. But I've heard a native speaker say practically the same thing as below with switched-around word order. I wonder if this construction is commonly used, too?

> L'iPhone 8 ***s'arrache***.

Comment: I'm not sure *L'iPhone 8 s'arrache.* will be correctly understood

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Toutes les structures actives peuvent se transformer à la voix passive normalement ainsi:
- on mange les pommes avec du miel => les pommes sont mangées avec du miel.

Mais on trouve également la forme plus courante pronominale avec se:

- on mange les pommes avec du miel => les pommes se mangent avec du miel.
- on prend le train le week-end => le train se prend le week-end.
- on achète les derniers modèles très vite => les derniers modèles s'achètent très vite.

Par hasard, s'arrache est aussi utilisé sous une forme pronominale: on se bat pour avoir ...

On aurait aussi pu dire (mais en retrouvant le sens premier): on arrache les iphones.